# How can autocomplete functionality can be implemented on observable array in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, autocomplete, observable

I am trying to apply autocomplete functionality in input box which will show the list of terms which are coming from observable Json array.

How can I achieve this using Angular 2 ?

Comment: Check this out: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: material design is not the option for me . can you suggest any other way ?

Comment: I tried different ways but in the end this is the best choose.